# Python Jarvis won't allow new playsound and if original is gone, no audio comes out and query doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have been following a YT tutorial on how to make a Jarvis AI in Python like the iron man movies. I've been using python for a while previously but I have never had this issue and I cannot figure it out for the life of me. Basically I have a few issues which I think are all related to the same cause. In my def wish(), I have an audio file using the playsound package. This plays and then everything else works fine but if I remove that playsound because I don't want it there anymore, the speak function doesn't work. It prints what it's supposed to say but doesn't actually say it. On top of that, the takecommand function stops working too. It doesn't take my audio after that. Alternative error is if I keep the playsound but try to add another, it gives me this error:
Error 305 for command:

```
        open "C:\Users\name\Downloads\JarvisStartup.mp3"
    Cannot specify extra characters after a string enclosed in quotation marks.
```

```
    Error 263 for command:
        close "C:\Users\name\Downloads\JarvisStartup.mp3"
    The specified device is not open or is not recognized by MCI.
Failed to close the file: "C:\Users\name\Downloads\JarvisStartup.mp3"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\name\PycharmProjects\Jarvis\main.py", line 110, in run
    self.TaskExecution()
  File "C:\Users\name\PycharmProjects\Jarvis\main.py", line 130, in TaskExecution
    wish()
  File "C:\Users\name\PycharmProjects\Jarvis\main.py", line 66, in wish
    playsound("C:\\Users\\name\\Downloads\\JarvisStartup.mp3")
  File "C:\Users\name\PycharmProjects\Jarvis\venv\lib\site-packages\playsound.py", line 72, in _playsoundWin
    winCommand(u'open {}'.format(sound))
  File "C:\Users\name\PycharmProjects\Jarvis\venv\lib\site-packages\playsound.py", line 64, in winCommand
    raise PlaysoundException(exceptionMessage)
playsound.PlaysoundException: 
    Error 305 for command:
        open "C:\Users\name\Downloads\JarvisStartup.mp3"
    Cannot specify extra characters after a string enclosed in quotation marks.
```

I don't understand it. Also, I only get that error if I add another playsound. The main, largest issue (1st one) doesn't give me an error. It just keeps the printed, un-said, statement forever until I just shut it off. Here is my code:

```
import sys
import time
import pyautogui
import pyttsx3
import pywhatkit
import requests
import speech_recognition as sr
import datetime
from statsbombpy import sb
import blink
import pyjokes
from roku import Roku
from PyQt5 import  QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer, QTime, QDate, Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QMovie
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.uic import loadUiType
from jarvisUi import Ui_MainWindow
import threading
from playsound import playsound
from gtts import gTTS
import tempfile
import python_weather
import asyncio
import os
import webbrowser
import subprocess


todo = []
roku = Roku('192.168.1.21')
WEATHER_URL = "https://api.openweathermap.org/geo/1.0/direct?q=location&limit=5&appid=6dd8aec1c47d033245f71a7c0b3f4172"


roku_remote_mode = False

engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
print(voices[0].id)
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[0].id)


def speak(audio):
    engine.say(audio)
    print(audio)
    engine.runAndWait()


def wish():
    playsound("C:\\Users\\name\\Downloads\\JarvisStartup.mp3")
    hour = datetime.datetime.now().hour
    speak("I require authorization to make sure it is you sir. Enter secret phrase")
    password = input("phrase input:")
    if password == "passowrd":

        if hour>=0 and hour <= 12:
            speak("good morning sir")
        elif hour>12 and hour<18:
            speak("good afternoon sir")
        else:
            speak("good evening sir")
        speak("how may i assist you")
    else:
        speak("incorrect. authorization not granted.")
def news():
    speak("according to the bbc,")
    import requests
    url = ('https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?'
           'sources=bbc-news&'
           'apiKey=25f98ddb1372448b8a8ba35ef5b35f87')
    main_page = requests.get(url).json()
    articles = main_page["articles"]
    head = []
    day=["first", "second", "third"]
    for ar in articles:
        head.append(ar["title"])
    for i in range (len(day)):
        speak(f"today's {day[i]} top news story is: {head[i]}")


def set_alarm(time_str):
    try:
        time_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(time_str, '%I:%M %p')
    except ValueError:
        speak("I'm sorry, I didn't understand the time.")
        return

    current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    delta = time_obj - current_time
    seconds = delta.seconds

    if seconds < 0:
        speak("I'm sorry, the time you specified has already passed.")
        return

    time.sleep(seconds)
    speak("Alarm!")


class MainThread(QThread):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainThread,self).__init__()

    def run(self):
        self.TaskExecution()

    def takecommand(self):
        r = sr.Recognizer()
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            print("listening...")
            r.pause_threshold = 1
            r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source, duration=0.5)
            audio = r.listen(source)
        try:
            print("recognizing...")
            self.query = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en')
            print(f"input: {self.query}")
        except Exception as e:
            speak("")
            return "none"
        return self.query


    def TaskExecution(self):
        wish()
        while True:
            self.query = self.takecommand().lower()
            if "open notepad" in self.query or "open my notepad" in self.query or "open the notepad" in self.query:
                npath = "C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\Microsoft.WindowsNotepad_11.2303.40.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\\Notepad\\Notepad.exe"
                os.startfile(npath)
            elif "command prompt" in self.query or "cmd" in self.query:
                os.system("start cmd")
            elif "play" in self.query:
                song = self.query.replace("play", "")
                pywhatkit.playonyt(song)
                speak(f"playing {song}")
            elif "pause the tv" in self.query or "pause tv" in self.query:
                roku.select()
            elif "resume the tv" in self.query or "resume tv" in self.query:
                roku.select()
            elif "open chrome" in self.query or "open google chrome" in self.query or "open google" in self.query:
                cpath = "C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe"
                os.startfile(cpath)
            elif "search youtube" in self.query:
                search = self.query.replace('search youtube', '')
                pywhatkit.playonyt(search)
            elif "goodnight" in self.query:
                speak("goodnight sir.")
            elif "search on google" in self.query:
                cm = self.query.replace('search on google', '')
                speak(f"searching for {cm}")
                webbrowser.open(f"{cm}")
            elif "open netflix on my tv" in self.query:
                netflix = roku[12]
                netflix.launch()
            elif "open disney on my tv" in self.query:
                disney = roku[291097]
                disney.launch()
            elif "open youtube on my tv" in self.query:
                youtube = roku[837]
                youtube.launch()
            elif "open hulu on my tv" in self.query:
                hulu = roku[2285]
                hulu.launch()
            elif "lockdown" in self.query:
                speak("initiating security protocol: lockdown")
                subprocess.run(["amixer", "-D", "pulse", "sset", "Master", "mute"])
                subprocess.run(["gnome-screensaver-command", "-l"])
                roku.home()

            elif "speak the alphabet" in self.query or "say the alphabet" in self.query:
                speak("a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z, perhaps maybe even a next time won't you sing with me?")
            elif "terminate" in self.query or "shutdown" in self.query or "turn off" in self.query:
                self.close()
            elif "test" in self.query:
                speak("peter piper picked a patch of pickled peppers. is everything working sir?")
            elif "wasn't talking to you" in self.query or "not talking to you" in self.query:
                speak("my apologies sir")
            elif "to my to do list" in self.query:
                speak("it has been added sir")
                todo.append(self.query.replace('to my to-do list', ''))
            elif "to to do list" in self.query:
                speak("it has been added sir")
                todo.append(self.query.replace('to to-do list', ''))
            elif "close notepad" in self.query:
                speak("closing notepad sir")
                os.system("taskill /f /im notepad.exe")
            elif "shut off the systems" in self.query or "shut off the system" in self.query or "shut down system" in self.query or "shut down the system" in self.query or "shut down the systems" in self.query:
                os.system("shutdown /s /t /5")
            elif "what do you think of Nigel" in self.query:
                speak("Nigel is my creator, therefore I am fond and loyal of him")
            elif "go to bed" in self.query or "going to bed" in self.query or "go to sleep" in self.query or "going to sleep" in self.query:
                speak("Sleep is important, good night sir")
            elif "thank you" in self.query or "thanks" in self.query:
                speak("you are welcome sir")
            elif "switch the window" in self.query:
                pyautogui.keyDown("alt")
                pyautogui.keyDown("tab")
                time.sleep(1)
                pyautogui.keyUp("alt")
            elif "the news" in self.query:
                news()
            elif "alarm" in self.query:
                set_alarm()
            elif "good morning" in self.query:
                speak("Good morning sir")

            elif "good afternoon" in self.query:
                speak("Good afternoon sir")

            elif "good evening" in self.query:
                speak("Good evening sir")
            elif "what time is it" in self.query:
                now = datetime.datetime.now()
                speak("sir, The time is " + now.strftime("%H:%M"))
            elif "goodbye" in self.query or "bye" in self.query:
                speak("Goodbye sir")
            elif "be back" in self.query or "be right back" in self.query:
                speak("right sir. I'll be sure not to go anywhere")
            elif "i'm back" in self.query:
                speak("welcome back sir")
            elif "how are you" in self.query:
                speak("I'm doing well sir, thank you for asking.")
            elif "what's your name" in self.query or "who are you" in self.query:
                speak("allow me to introduce myself. I am jarvis, a virtual assistant for Nigel")
            elif "hello" in self.query or "hi" in self.query or "hey" in self.query or "greetings" in self.query:
                speak("hello sir")
            elif "joke" in self.query:
                joke = pyjokes.get_joke()
                speak(joke)
            elif "sad" in self.query:
                speak("sorry to hear that sir. perhaps a joke might cheer you up")
                joke = pyjokes.get_joke()
                speak(joke)
            elif "print my to do list" in self.query or "what's my to do list" in self.query or "what's on my to-do list" in self.query:
                speak("your to-do list holds the following.")
                speak(todo)
            elif "stop the music" in self.query or "stop music" in self.query or "music stop" in self.query or "music off" in self.query or "music turn off" in self.query:
                speak("turning off the music sir")
                os.system("taskill /f /im chrome.exe")
            elif "close chrome" in self.query or "close google" in self.query:
                speak("closing chrome sir")
                os.system("taskill /f /im chrome.exe")
            elif "where am i" in self.query or "where are we" in self.query:
                speak("checking location now sir")
                try:
                    ipAdd = requests.get('https://api.ipify.org').text
                    print(ipAdd)
                    url = 'https://get.geojs.io/v1/ip/geo' + ipAdd + '.json'
                    geo_requests = requests.get(url)
                    geo_data = geo_requests.json()
                    city = geo_data['city']
                    country = geo_data['country']
                    speak(f"the system tells me we are approximately in {city} city of {country}")
                except Exception as e:
                    speak("sorry sir, I can not seem to retract enough information of our current location")
                    pass
            elif "hide this folder" in self.query:
                os.system("attrib +h /s /d")
                speak("I have hidden this folder sir")
            elif "unhide this folder" in self.query or "make this folder visible" in self.query:
                os.system("attrib -h /s /d")

startExecution = MainThread()

class Main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.startTask)
        self.ui.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.close)

    def startTask(self):
        self.ui.movie = QtGui.QMovie("C:\\Users\\name\\Documents\Jarvis\\background.gif")
        self.ui.label.setMovie(self.ui.movie)
        self.ui.movie.start()
        self.ui.movie = QtGui.QMovie("C:\\Users\\name\\Documents\Jarvis\\hud_loading.gif")
        self.ui.label_2.setMovie(self.ui.movie)
        self.ui.movie.start()
        self.ui.movie = QtGui.QMovie("C:\\Users\\name\\Documents\Jarvis\\circular.gif")
        self.ui.label_3.setMovie(self.ui.movie)
        self.ui.movie.start()
        timer = QTimer(self)
        timer.timeout.connect(self.showTime)
        timer.start(1000)
        startExecution.start()
    def showTime(self):
        current_time = QTime.currentTime()
        current_date = QDate.currentDate()
        label_time = current_time.toString('hh:mm:ss')
        label_date = current_date.toString(Qt.ISODate)
        self.ui.textBrowser.setText(label_time)
        self.ui.textBrowser_2.setText(label_date)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
jarvis = Main()
jarvis.show()
exit(app.exec_())
```

(I changed my file location user to "name" and the weather api location just for security)

I tried to use pydub which didn't work. I also copied and edited the code until it worked. The issue was that it was like so widdled down that I didn't have the UI or any of my functions besides speak and takecommand. Other than that, I really don't know what else to do. If anyone can help, I'd appreciate it a lot.